# d3.tree => transform does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, firebug, d3.js

I create a tree layout graph using d3js. The nodes are clickable to toggle showing the children. The child node should be inserted at a predefined position and then transitioned to the desired location. The problem is that the insertion coordinates are always off. When debugging with Firebug, it shows that directly after appending the new node its coordinates are x = 51.42857142857142 and y = 200.0 even though the line
    `.attr("transform", "translate(90,100)" )` should alter them (I use fixed values here, to pin down the problem further.

Where is my mistake?

Full code:

```
// Toggle children.
function toggle(d) {
   if (d.children) {
     d._children = d.children;
     d.children = null;
   } else {
     d.children = d._children;
     d._children = null;
  }
} 

function toggleAll(d) {
   if (d.children) {
      d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
      toggle(d);
   }
}

function update(source) {
   // Node movement delay
   var duration = d3.event && 1500;

   // Compute the new tree layout.
   var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();

   // Normalize for fixed-depth.
   nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 100; });

   // Update the nodes…
   var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
     .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
   var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", "translate(90,100)" )
    .on("click", function(d) { toggle(d); update(d); });

  nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);


  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 4.5)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "red" : "#fff"; });



  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
     .duration(duration)
     .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
    .remove();

 // While moving the nodes, they need to shrink
 nodeExit.select("circle")
   .attr("r", 1e-6);


    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
   });
}


var i = 0, root;
var radius = 960 / 2;
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
   .size([360, radius - 120]);
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
   .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI]; });

var vis = d3.select("#body").append("svg:svg")
   .attr("width", radius * 2)
   .attr("height", radius * 2 - 50)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

d3.json("flare.json", function(json) {
  root = json;
  root.x0 = 0;
  root.y0 = 0;


  // Initialize the display to show a few nodes.
  root.children.forEach(toggleAll);
  toggle(root.children[1]);

  update(root);
});
```

Comment: `transform`s don't alter the coordinates you'll see in the DOM inspector -- how are you determining where the new node is at? | JSfiddles are important if you want to increase your chance of getting help on SO.

Comment: heres a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/94EWe/

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do? You fiddle is a lot of data with no explanation of what your actual problem is. Maybe include a much smaller tree and an explanation of the desired behavior.

Comment: @AndrewHubbs the fiddle has a lot of data because it is using the flare.json data that Sven mentions in his question.  I started out trying to take a look at the issue, put together a fiddle of the exact code (minus ajax call) with data that is mentioned in the question for testing, but then realised I needed more information on Sven's intention.  It made sense to me to post the fiddle to help the next guy.

Comment: If you want to alter the x and y values, then you should use:
someElement
.attr("x", someXvalue)
.attr("y", someYvalue);

If you use the transform, the element WILL be moved according to the transform value, but the coordinates (x and y) WONT change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the insertion coordinates by adjusting the initial `transform`, i.e. changing

```
.attr("transform", "translate(90,100)")
```

For example, if you want to insert the new nodes at the position of their parent node, you can do this by passing a reference to the parent element to the `update` function and getting its `transform` value:

```
var sourceNode = d3.select(parentElement);

// Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", parentElement ? sourceNode.attr("transform") : "translate(90,100)")
    .on("click", function (d) {
    toggle(d);
    update(d, this);
});
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/94EWe/7/).